# Redshift skip entire file which contains error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there any way/option or workaround to skip the entire file which contains bad entries , while loading the data from S3 to Redshift.
Please note that I am not talking about skipping the entries that are invalid in the file, but the entire file which contains bad entry or record.

Answer (score 2):

By default Redshift fails entire file if you don't supply Maxerror option in Copy command. Its default behavior.

```
 copy catdemo from 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/category_pipe.txt' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>' region 'us-west-2';
```

Above command will fail entire file and will not load any data from given file. Read the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) for more information.

If you specify, `Maxerror` option then only it ignores records upto that # from particular file.

```
 copy catdemo from 's3://awssampledbuswest2/tickit/category_pipe.txt' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::<aws-account-id>:role/<role-name>' region 'us-west-2' MAXERROR 500;
```

In above example `Redshift` will tolerate up-to `500` bad records.

I hope this answers your question, but If it doesn't please update the question and I will refocus the answer.

Comment: Hey Hi,you have answered one of my question previously. Here my question is I want to skip the file not the entries. I don't want to load a single entry from that file if the file contains any bad record. I don't want to use MaxError because it will load the records till it faces the error line. I don't want that , I want to discard the entire file and proceed ahead.

Comment: Are you asking that if you have multiple files and one of fails because any bad, you want to move on and process next one? Then you have to do exception handling in application, can't be just by copy command.

Comment: Ok, Actually I am using a ETL tool so there are already components to do the loading. I just wanted to know if it is any other option to enable or to set to handle this situation. So basically it seems that there is no option to this.
Thank you for your help and support.